# Using PHP to insert values in MySQL database from Android app not working?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I am trying to insert some values into a MySQL-database using PHP. I am fairly certain that my android code is correct, but I have very limited understanding of PHP. Am I doing something obvious wrong?

```
<?

$databasehost = "MyIPAdress:port";
$databasename = "databaseIWant";
$databaseusername = "UserWithPerms";
$databasepassword = "CorrectPassword";

$con = mysql_connect($databasehost,$databaseusername,$databasepassword) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($databasename) or die(mysql_error());

$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$school = $_POST['school'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO users(username, password, school) VALUES ('$email', '$password', '$school');

$query_exec = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close();

?>
```

Here is the android code as well: (Java)

When a user registers this method gets called:

```
private void RegisterNewUser(String username, String password) {
        RegisterUserOnNetwork regUser = new RegisterUserOnNetwork();
        regUser.execute(username, password);
    }

class RegisterUserOnNetwork extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    private Exception exception;

protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", strings[0]));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", strings[1]));

    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new     HttpPost("http://IpAdress/RegisterUser.php");
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            Log.e("RESULT", EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity) + "l");

            return "Gebruiker suksesvol geskep!";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Bediener kon nie bereik word nie.";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested your connection to the database ? Is it working ?

Comment: I have another C# application connecting to the same database and it works (although it doesn't use PHP). So the database is working :)

Comment: Because it's usually a pain to setup a connection between the Android client & the database using MySQL (for the first time), so you really should worry about the configuration first.

Comment: Yes, it's a horrible pain... I've done it before and still I can never get it right. I will post my android code as well?

Comment: Well like I said, it's really not worth the pain if you are not certain that you've established a connection to the database. You need to test it.

Comment: The result from the httpEntity is: 
AsyncTask #3 calls detatch()

Sadly I have no idea what that means :/

Comment: I guess the missing `"` to end the `$sql` string is just a typo and correct in your PHP code?

Comment: Sorry but is it not that you have username instead of email? So it looks like your trying to POST to email but your using username. "INSERT INTO users(username, password, school) should be "INSERT INTO users(email, password, school)

Answer (score 1):

No school is send to PHP. Also PHP error will be helpful in debuging.

Answer (score 0):

You are not posting data for "School" you should add another line of code in ur android app

```
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("school", YOUR_DATA));
```

Comment: The school line was accidentally left out of my code snippet but is indeed in the application's code...

Answer (score 0):

**Add these lines before DeafultHttpClient**

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

**Add internet permission to your Manifest file.**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**PHP code.**

```
<?php
$databasehost = "MyIPAdress:port";
$databasename = "databaseIWant";
$databaseusername = "UserWithPerms";
$databasepassword = "CorrectPassword";

$con = mysqli_connect($databasehost, $databaseusername, $databasepassword, $databasename) or die(mysqli_error());

$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$school = $_POST['school'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO users(username, password, school) VALUES ('$email', '$password', '$school')";

$query_exec = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysql_error());
mysqli_close();
?>
```

Comment: The closing double quotes are missing yet. Notice, that interpolation of `$_POST` values is highly vulnerable to SQL injection.